# WAVEFORMATEX - how to read codecdata at the end?

Tags: c++, media, wav

I've a WAVEFORMATEX struct with some codecdata at the end of it (10 bytes).

I'm using C++.

How do I access the data at the end? (this is a purely technical question).

I tried :

```
WAVEFORMATEX* wav = (WAVEFORMATEX*)pmt->pbFormat;
    WORD me = wav->cbSize;
    wav = wav + sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX);
    BYTE* arr = new BYTE[me];
    memcpy(arr, (BYTE*)wav, me);
```

Didnt work.

Thanks

Roey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done a little mistake in pointer arithmetic. After

```
wav = wav + sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX);
```

wav points far beyond the end of the buffer (because wav is not CHAR* but WAVEFORMATEX*). You need to write:

```
wav = wav + 1;
```

Comment: Hi, would you please help me on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503611/audio-manipulation-and-delete-some-part-of-the-audio) I'm trying to do this about one month but I'm not succeed on it, please help me, any idea may helps

Comment: @mopebi Yes, no problem.