# Audio manipulation and delete some part of the audio

Tags: c++, c, voice, voice-recording, winmm

I'm new in voice codding, now I am succeed to recording microphone in the files and save each 10 seconds in a file with `SaveRecordtoFile` function(doing this with no problem)

Now I want to delete for example 2 seconds from the recorded data so my output will be 8 seconds instead of 10, in the `randomTime` array `0` is the number of seconds witch I want to be delete...

In a for-loop I copy the data of `waveHeader->lpData` in a new buffer `if (randomTime[i] == '1')`

It seems this is a true algorithm and should works but the problem is the outputs, some of the outputs are good (about 70% or more) but some of them are corrupted

I think I have a mistake in the code but I debug this code for some days and I don't understand what is the problem?

And as my 70% or more of outputs are good I think It's not because of bytes or samples

Comment: Where is there any `C++` in the code you posted?  It looks all `C`.  Second, do you need to post all of this code to show how you "erase" an item from an array?  The efficient way is to merely swap the items to erase to the end of the array in the loop, and after the loop, just one call to memcpy to "erase" the swapped out items  (this is how `std::remove_if` works in C++).  Your attempt is calling mempy repeatedly in a loop, which is very inefficient.  For each iteration, you're moving an entire block to cover up the hole, and that isn't a good way to do this, even though it may "work".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 1: I need to show how to record data, 2: every time I post a part of the code some one like you comments me that post the complete code 3: I know the solution does not depend on C or C++ so every one how knows C or C++ can helps on it **4: thanks for your answer but I don't understand your solution, would you please explain more?**

Comment: You can post complete code, but show the concept that you're trying to accomplish.  What does this really have to do with audio files?  It seems to be a very generic problem, which could be boiled down to "how to erase items from an array when ...".  It doesn't matter if the array consists of audio data, file data, an array of widgets, etc.  As to my solution, this is just basic algorithms.  You have an array of N items, and you want to erase items that match a certain criteria in an efficient (and safe) manner.  Hopefully you see your memcpy in a loop is a naive way to do this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand that the problem is calling mempy repeatedly in a loop, but I don't understand your efficient way, I don't understand how to swap the items, how does it helps to solve my problem, I didn't do something like this `swap the items to erase to the end of the array in the loop, and after the loop, just one call to memcpy to "erase" the swapped out items`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie would you please give me a sample code that helps me to Implement your solution? or post this code as an answer please

Comment: Looking at the code, swapping would be hard to do, but you can certainly minimize the number of calls to memcpy.  What if the data were "011111111"?  You would be issuing 9 calls to memcpy instead of just one.  Or this "0111001111"?  You would only need 2 calls to memcpy, not 7.  You start out with a good stream, but all of this very-hard-to-follow logic creates a stream that seems to be bad.  Before embarking on anything else, have you verified via debugging that 1) Given a good stream, if you remove one sample, the stream of bytes is exactly as you expect in terms of the byte data?

Comment: If so, there are much easier and safer ways to do this.  You just need to store in an array of value pairs, where the first of the pair tells you the start of the data to copy, and the second value the length.  You build this array up, all without touching any of the data at first.  Then when done, it is just a matter of going through the array, calling memcpy.  That is much easier to follow than trying to manipulate the stream in mid-flight like you are doing now.  And why the calls to `HeapAlloc`?  Won't a simple `std::vector<char>` sized to the appropriate size be easier to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can break a sample apart, after that the stream is out of sync and you hear a loud noise.

**How it happens?** Your sample size is 4 bytes. So you must never copy anything that is not a multiple of 4. 10 seconds of audio will take 10x48000×4=1920000 bytes. However `Sleep(10000)` will always be near 10 seconds but not exactly 10 seconds. So you can get 1920012 bytes. Then you do:

```
dwSamplePerSec = waveHeader->dwBytesRecorded / 10; // 10 Secs
```

that returns 192001 (which is not multiple of 4) and the steam gets out of sync. If you're lucky you receive 1920040 bytes for 10 second and that remains multiple of 4 after division on 10 and you're ok.

Comment: thank you, you are the best, I wish I could vote-up your answer 100 times.